# Admin login don't redirect to panel

Tags: php, prestashop

I import a project on my local but I don’t have an access to the admin panel. I enter the right id/password, but after this, it's redirect me to the login page again with an url with params like this :

```
controller=AdminLogin&token=beea5c47ad0213dbc06a5fb335bda892&redirect=AdminDashboard
```

I tried a lot of stuff but nothing get me to the admin panel. It seems to have a problem with the session or the cookie..

I also tried many environments : windows (xampp), debian, ubuntu

And differents php version : 5.6, 7.0, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4

My version of Prestashop is 1.7.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of problems in prestashop are related to cookies (I guess you tried from incognito, if not give it a try) or to some data that needs to be changed on your db.

You should check the db for occurrencies of the remote assress (e.g. https://myecommerce.com) and modify them with your local address (e.g. http://localhost)

Look for the remote address in the tables `ps_configuration` and `ps_shop_url` (I'm assuming your db prefix is `ps` in case is different use your own) and change the occurrencies you find according to the local address, that should solve the issue or at least part of it.

Let me know,

Simone

Comment: I tried to replace every occurrencies of the remote address, but that change nothing, also in every link in the front goes on 404 page. If you got another idea, I take it..

Comment: did you check your htaccess? Is there any hardcoded url? If you are lucky deactivate and reactivate Friendly Url can fix htaccess problems

Comment: Ok, I finally get my bug resolved : I installed mamp pro to get a domain name in local and everything works

Comment: If you are on windows I would suggest to try Laragon. Anyway, Prestashop works without local domain as well, just using ip:port where it is served (127.0.0.1:3000 for example) or localhost:p and setting the shop url accordingly, it didn't work for you?

Comment: No, ip:port or localhost:port didn't work, but Laragon seems rly good, I will try, thanks !